# How to bind a multiple rows from access table by query in runtime using XtraReport Winforms?

Tags: c#, winforms, devexpress, xtrareport

How to bind a multiple rows to report in label or table ?? If my table is single row I can easily bind and it display in label and also display in table but my table consist of 2 or 3 rows it wont display. How to show multiple row in a report ? I need o filter it according to which item is selected ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't bind it directly. Use `BeforePrint` event for that label (not for the report!)

```
private void xrLabel4_BeforePrint(object sender, System.Drawing.Printing.PrintEventArgs e) {
  var id = this.GetCurrentColumnValue<int>("ID"); // get value of field ID for this row
  var lines = GetRows(id); // for demo only: returns string[]
  (sender as XRLabel).Lines = lines;
}
```

Don't forget to set property `Multiline` to true.

Comment: Hi Marko, Thanks I get now idea and I test it working successfully but I have one doubt, Am getting two pages that second is empty page but my 1st page itself less information. Why it show two pages ? Whats error ?

Comment: Check property PaperKind on your report.